# Why won't simple node.js app doesn't respond on Windows Azure VM?

Tags: node.js, iis, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am new to node.js, so hopefully I'm missing something obvious.

I have a Windows Azure VM running Windows Server 2012.  It has IIS installed and simple, static sites returning static HTML works fine.

I have installed node.js on this server (via Chocolatey).  I've created a simple Hello World node.js application (test.js):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Hello World');
});
app.listen(80);
```

I fire this up on the server via: `node test.js`

It works fine on the server when I browse via `http://localhost/test.js`
It is unreachable from my client machine's browser via `http://<servername>/test.js`

I have:

- created an endpoint on my VM to allow port 80 via TCP;
- created a firewall rule on my VM to allow port 80 traffic
- a web site on IIS for port 80 and it's running

When I change the above code to listen on a different port (e.g. 2368) and make the appropriate endpoint and firewall rules, everything works great both on the client and the server.  I have no problem accessing the site.

What am I missing with port 80 here?  Why can't I access my test file via port 80, but I can access it via a different port?

Hopefully it's something obvious.  Thank you in advance.